# How can you have more used_pages than total_pages when looking at sys.allocation_units?

Tags: sql-server, data-pages

When looking at a database, this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.allocation_units a WHERE (a.total_pages - a.used_pages) < 0
```

surprisingly returns a row. This is the result:

```
+--------------------+------+-------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+------------+------------+
| allocation_unit_id | type |  type_desc  |   container_id    | data_space_id | total_pages | used_pages | data_pages |
+--------------------+------+-------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  72057594058702848 |    1 | IN_ROW_DATA | 72057594047692800 |             1 |         105 |        111 |         93 |
+--------------------+------+-------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

My understanding is that pages are 8kb groupings of space on the disk (Is this correct?)

How can I have more `used_pages` than I have `total_pages`?

Comment: Is that a HEAP?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik, I get similar results on clustered tables.

Comment: Can you find an example where the difference is bigger than 8 (ie. one mixed extent size) ?

Comment: And also, does the difference persists after running [`DBCC UPDATEUSAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-updateusage-transact-sql)?

Comment: @RemusRusanu: When I run UPDATEUSAGE on that database, the query above then returns no rows

Comment: @RemusRusanu, I'm actually new to the concept of pages and data storage structures in general (I don't have a comsci background). I'd be interested to learn more, but at the moment I don't really know what the significance of 8kb pages is, or why that is a `mixed extent size`. The MSDN reference isn't great here either.. Can you point me to some good sources?

Comment: @ZachSmith Paul Randal's blog: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-an-extent/

Comment: If it corrects itself after `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE` it means is nothing more than Yet Another Allocation Rollback page count tracking bug. Since such issues are 1) very hard to repro (one can figure it out form the log, but usually by the time is discovered the log is long lost) and 2) mostly benign , these bugs are seldom tracked down. I myself fixed a few back in the day, but I'm sure there still are more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is related to the fact that this DMV is updated asynchronously behind the scenes.  Per the [sys.allocation_units BOL page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-allocation-units-transact-sql):

> ...the values returned by sys.allocation_units immediately after dropping or truncating a large object may not reflect the actual disk space available

While this implies only drops and/or truncates won't be tracked in real-time, I just ran the same query against one of my environments where nothing is ever dropped or deleted and am getting similar behavior to your results.  I suspect this view just is updated in the background and whatever it is that has to trigger to spawn the update hasn't happened yet.

Hopefully someone else has a better answer as I'd be interested to know for certain as well.